# Highchairs: Change width of every other gridline

Tags: highcharts

All,
  I've created a line chart using highcharts that implements gridlines every 10 units using the following

```
xAxis = {
            tickInterval: 10,
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            gridLineColor: 'red'
    }
```

Now what I'm trying to do is increase the width of every 25th grid line by 1 for a total width of 2.

I feel like there should be any easy way to do this but I can't seem to find an API call for it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use gridLines and minorGridLines in your case. You may have different width of your gridLines then. Here you can find information about this options: 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minorGridLineWidth
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minorTickInterval

```
xAxis: {
  minorGridLineWidth: 1,
  minorTickInterval: 12.5,
  gridLineWidth: 3,
  tickInterval: 25
},
```

And here you can see live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/dtepd3jq/1/

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `addPlotLine()` function, which you can find in the API documentation here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.addPlotLine.

From there, you can find a simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/axis-addplotline/

Depending on how dynamic your data are, you could write a Javascript or jQuery function that adds a new plot line with the necessary attributes (including the increasing line width) at every Nth interval in your chart.

I hope this is helpful in your research!